# In firebug, how do I find out all of the css styles being applied to a particular element?

Tags: css, firebug

I'm way buried in many nested levels of css, and I can't tell which style layer/level is messing up my display. How can I find out everything that's being applied to a particular element?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Click Inspect (upper left) to select the element you want to check

then on the right panel select the tab labeled "Style". It will also tell you from which .css file that particular property comes from

Answer (score 2):

Right click the element and choose "Inspect Element", then you should see the element and all of the CSS rules which contributed to it. You can modify the rules simply by clicking and editing the values to try out different things to correct problems.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Inspect button. Click on the item you're interested in. On the right-hand side, Firebug shows all the styles of the element, and the file + line number they originiated from.

Find the style you're trying to apply, and see if it has a stroke through it. If it does, it's being overridden by something higher in the hierarchy.

Now you have to decide how you want to solve it. Either by making your css entry more specific to the item in question, or modifying your styles in some other manner.

Answer (score 1):

from the 'CSS' tab, click on "Inspect" and then click on the element. All the applied styles (and their origin) will show up on the right hand side.